# How do I add multiple objects to a table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I add multiple objects in the same cell?

```
func getNowPlayingItem() {
    if let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem {
        let title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
        let artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] as? String
        let album = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] as? String
        println("Song: \(title)")
        println("Artist: \(artist)")
        println("Album: \(album)")
        println("\n")


        self.add = [Play(name: title!)]
        self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0

    }
}
```

I tried modifying `[Play(name: title!)]` to  `[Play(name: title! + artist! + album!)]`, but only the title shows up, I'm guessing that only the first object will appear. How can I get all three to show up on three separate lines, but in the same cell?

Comment: You could possibly resize the title label programmatically and make it multi-line, or create a custom cell with three labels so you can fine tune the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string substitution i.e "\(title!) \(artist!) \(album !)" instead.

Comment: like this?  `self.add = [Play(name: (title!)(artist!)(album!)]`

Comment: Yes but it needs to be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

In `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` set following property for your UITableViewCell.

```
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3;
cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

By default, your UITableViewCell only display the first line of text. So, you need to set numberOfLines to 3.
Then:

```
self.add = [Play(name: "\(title!)\n\(artist!)\n\(album !)")]
```

Notice the newline "\n" character.